# How to connect to Mongo DB in Pyspark using spark session through zeppelin

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, database-connection, connection-string, apache-zeppelin

How to connect to Mongo DB Using Spark session using zeppelin

I am using the below script but am getting a authentication error?

In the uri I am passing the connection string/port/user and password.

people.write.format("mongodb").mode("append").option("database",
"people").option("collection", "contacts").save()

Comment: Maybe this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authentication failure while trying to save to mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb)